# Is there a list of Orthodox shuls in Israel, U.S. and Canada that have choirs regularly?

Tags: tefilla, synagogue

I've been to 2 shuls that I know have choirs during services on Shabbat & Yom Tov:

- Spanish Portugese shul in New York City
- Sha'ar Hashamayim in Montreal

Is there a list of shuls, or can someone post a list of a few that he knows of with links to their web site, if it exists. Also please include the shuls *nusach*, esp, if it is not :standard" Nusach Ashkenaz / Sefard. (E.g. Spanish Portugese has their own Sefard Nusach which is a bit different from Nusach Ari.)

Comment: The Spanish-Portuguese nusach is like Nusach Sefard (the Ashkenazi one) but without the additions of the Arizal; so pretty much void of kabbalah.

Comment: I really dislike the idea of a shul choir because it seems a lot like a church to me. Just my opinion.

Comment: @ezra. Matter of preference. I guess, then, you may not have enjoyed the Levi'im singing in the Bet Hamikdash, either :-) I won't discuss the quality of the typical *duchenen* choir, now.

Comment: Khal Adath Jeshurun in Washington Heights (aka Breuer's) has a choir

Comment: @wfb Considering that I used to live in that neighborhood and I was part of the school choir as a kid, and one of my close friends was a *Yekke*, you would think that someone would have told me about that back then. I guess there's another reason to revisit my old neighborhood.

Comment: @DanF - I think it has everything to do with style.

Comment: @ezra Got it. You may want to listen to some works by Lewandowski - one of a few composers that wrote choral works for davening. You can probably locate it on YouTube.